# How to maintain width of an image when scaling in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep some images side-by-side while maintaining the height. I have tried this:

```
.row {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row img {
  width: 16%;
  height: auto;

}
```

This is how it displays on the web:
[image]

I want the height to be the same, what do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: your goal here ins't clear at all. you want the images to horizontally shrink while maintaining the height? IE you want the images to warp? You should also include your HTML in any event.

Comment: can you see the height of the images in the red box? I want them to be equal @bryan60

Comment: then set the height to 100%, but this will end up in your images warping, which usually isn't what web developers are after.

Comment: @ekeith can you include html too, so we can test that?

Comment: might want to look at the actual dimensions of those images as well

Comment: yeah you have a point! @cidicles

Answer (score 1):

The point is to make the images responsive:

```css
.row {
  /*float: left;*/
  display: flex; /* displays the images inline */
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.row img { /* responsiveness */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

VXp's image responsive code is perfect to get all the images of same height.

I have even added a wide image, it gets converted to full height as well.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
  height: 200px;
}

.row img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/10/The_Lego_Movie_poster.jpg">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/ca/The-cutter-movie.jpg">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/29/Legend-of-a-rabbit-movie-poster-2011-1020694984%2B%281%29.jpg">
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/d/d7/Frozen_movie.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131120182859">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Pinkmovieposter.jpg">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/79/The_Faculty_movie_poster.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpJ7Y.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: if i set it to something fixed say 200px, if I reduce my browser or switch to mobile it looks squished

Comment: I am trying to replicate it in codepen, just give me 5 min.